# React controlled input's value is being ignored if state value is null / undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone please explain why the surname input's value is still showing up on screen as i type even though the prop is set to an object's property that does not exist?

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "John",
    surname: "Travolta",
  });

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          placeholder="name"
          value={state.name}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="surname"
          placeholder="surname"
          value={state.surnameeee}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It seems as if the browser thinks if the input's value is undefined / null it will take a user's input.

I would expect the controlled surname input to stay blank?

Comment: I think it’s because as far as React is concerned, the value of the input hasn’t changed, so React doesn’t re-render the input element. So it just keeps whatever you typed into it.

Comment: if the value is null, or undefined input behaves like uncontrolled, if you set  surnameeee: "", (empty string) it will be set to that input